# onCreateMenuOptions differ on newer Apis?

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

In one class I inflate the action bar to find an item and then I return super.oncreatemenuoptions(menu) then in the other class I just use menu.finditem... In the onCreateMenuOptions method without inflating because when I inflated it again two of the items were created. It works fine on Api 15 and 16 but android 4.2.2 throws a null pointer exception whenever I try to use the item in the second class. The phone it crashes on is a Samsung Galaxy s4. Is there any firmware issues with Samsung? Is there anyway around this by checking api in my code?
Class 1:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
Menuinflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
inflated.inflate (R.menu.actionbar, menu);
MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.search);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Class 2:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
SearchView SearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem (R.id.search).getActionView();
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code, it will be easily to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the search view android:showAsAction in the menu folder xml from "ifroom" to "always." Also moving the searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this) from onCreateView to onCreateOptionsMenu but now when I do that it wont work on the older device and vice-versa when I move it back... I think this is a bug with api 19 or newer apis or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sdk build version value of device pragmatically within your code by this line.
"Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);"
and you can get release build vesion by this line.
"String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;"
But,I didn,t understand why do you need to know the version.
I think the problem is with your Sdk.Try to use the updated SDK and Updated IDE.Or try to create a new project and copy all classes in that new project.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: You have to inflate the action bar in each class.Problem is somewhere else.Can You show me your menu file "actionbar.xml"?

Comment: Compare your code with the link given below.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html
The proper way to use the Action bar is given in this link.Read this link completely.It will vanish all your confusions about Action Bar.

Comment: When I inflate it in both classes two items appear on my kindle device

Comment: Check your menu_main.xml class in res/menu folder.
What you have given the value in app:showAsAction="value"?
I think the problem is with your menu file.Re check your menu_main.xml file.